# How to add custom buttons to my keyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, uikeyboard

I would like to have a keyboard like this in my application:

[image: Google Chrome App]

How to realize this?
How to add the row with the several commandos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add buttons by implementing the [`inputAccessoryView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIResponder/inputAccessoryView) for the [`UIResponder`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class).

Comment: Thx for your post, I used google and found a tutorial for this: http://gabriel-tips.blogspot.de/2011/05/input-accessory-view-how-to-add-extra.html

Answer (score 1):

What I did was create a keyboard from scratch. Use two `UIViews` and buttons in the Fist view wich is on the bottom. Set user interaction disabled on these buttons and then with this code here:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:keyboardView];
    //here loops all labels
    for(UIButton *keyButton in keyboardView.subviews){
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(keyButton.frame,touchPoint)&&keyButton.enabled) {
            keyButton.highlighted = YES;
            for(UIButton *bigKey in keyboardTextView.subviews){
                if (bigKey.currentTitle==keyButton.currentTitle) {
                    bigKey.hidden=NO;
                }
                else{
                    bigKey.hidden=YES;
                }
            }
        }
        else if(!CGRectContainsPoint(keyButton.frame,touchPoint)){
            keyButton.highlighted = NO;
        }
    }
}
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:keyboardView];
    //here loops all labels
    for(UIButton *keyButton in keyboardView.subviews){
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(keyButton.frame,touchPoint)&&keyButton.enabled) {
            keyButton.highlighted = YES;
            for(UIButton *bigKey in keyboardTextView.subviews){
                if (bigKey.currentTitle==keyButton.currentTitle) {
                    bigKey.hidden=NO;
                }
                else{
                    bigKey.hidden=YES;
                }
            }
        }
        else if(!CGRectContainsPoint(keyButton.frame,touchPoint)){
            keyButton.highlighted = NO;
        }
    }
}
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:keyboardView];
    for(UIButton *keyButton in keyboardView.subviews){
        keyButton.highlighted = NO;
        if(CGRectContainsPoint(keyButton.frame,touchPoint) && keyButton.enabled == YES){
            keyButton.enabled = NO;
            letterUsedString=keyButton.currentTitle;
            // right here you can use the letter Used String.
        }
    }
    for(UIButton *bigKey in keyboardTextView.subviews){
        bigKey.hidden=YES;
    }
}
```

All you need is two `IBOutlets` to the views, `keyboardTextView` and Keyboard View. I will upload some files so you can see my keyboard. So the first view is the buttons you pressed, an image in the background of a button. And the second view is the buttons highlighted. If you implement that code and connect the two `IBOutlets`, it will work like a keyboard. Any variables that aren't recognized just add to your `.h`. When my buttons where pressed I highlighted them which changed the image from:

[image: this]

to :

[image: this]

And then my magnified button above image would be:

[image: this.]

Just place your buttons how you want them, and put magnified buttons above. The magnified button view is visible, but all the buttons inside are hidden until you press. I hope my code helps, you'll have to do the storyboard on your own.

Comment: Thanks, I hope others will also understand it without the storyboard file to help.